# Program or language to create "bots" for games

Tags: macros, artificial-intelligence, bots

I want to code some simple AI to play same games. Simple stuff, like logging in to an account, searching for an image on the screen, clicking on certain points or pressing key strokes after a certain amount of time. Since the idea is to keep it simply, I don't want anything too complex, so working from the scratch is something I don't want to do.

My question here is if you could list me the ways to do this fairly quickly. Programs or languages. I know of some Macros programs like AutoHotkey. In what regards programming languages I know C++ and Python, but unless I can get good libraries (one for manipulating the mouse, other to manipulate key strokes) I don't think they will come in handy.

P.S.

In case you are wondering why, the reason I want to do this is that some of my friends are addicted to social games where they are required to meet certain random criteria's (like introducing a phrase every 12 hours) to allow them to play competitively against other players. So I, as a programmer, want to try to make this burden (that doesn't add ANYTHING to the games) a little bit smaller.

Comment: I used [Java's Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) a few times for this (however, it doesn't work on a fair amount of non-browser games).

Answer (score 2):

Let me get this straight.
You want to write an AI that plays social games and you want a list of how to do this quickly.

I think you will get a fair deal of downvotes on this, but what the heck:

The easy solution is Selenium Webdriver, it is an automation tool, often used for testing.
You could record the basics in the IDE, then export it to Eclipse and code a more advanced structure in Java.
It should be the path of least resistance for you.

Comment: It's a nice answer, I think. Solves the problem with the minimal effort and decent results. And to OP - if the games are WWW-based, clicking on "position on the screen" would be pretty useless compared to DOM operations

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need it to work under linux I recommend [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Moving the mouse, clicking, pressing keys is very simple. It also can [check for pixel colors](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelGetColor.htm) in the screen, leave an icon in the tray or run some functions when you press custom commands.
It is very simple and complete. Here is a list of all functions you can use by default (you can add libraries too): http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions.htm

I've also used Java Robot but if you want a game bot, try Autoit first.

Comment: AutoIT documentation doesn't mention reading pixel colors.  I want to make a bit and am also trying to figure out what language and tools i should use.  I need to be able to detect visuals on screen and press buttons based on the detected visuals.

Comment: @SabatinoOgnibene the AutoIT documentation does mention exactly that function: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelGetColor.htm it is on the list of functions link I provided.